# Regex matching complex string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have following exemplary strings:

```
- FCF_VD_ID,
- [FCF_VD_Alert_L1, ..., FCF_VD_Alert_L8],
- FCF_VD_SyncID,
- [FCF_VRU_Alert_FCV, FCF_VRU_Alert_A ..., FCF_VRU_Alert_H],
- [COM_Cam_Frame_1, ..., COM_Cam_Frame_8]
```

And I need to extract some specific parts from these strings. Specifically I need the core name of each string which in the above cases is everything till enumerator.
As an enumerator I treat L1->L8, FCV, A->H, 1->8.

As output I need to get two strings:

```
core, enum = re.match(regex, string)
```

Example:

```
FCF_Alert_L1 -> FCF_Alert, L1
FCF_SyncID -> FCF_Sync_ID, None
FCF_VRU_Alert_FCV -> FCF_VRU_Alert, FCV
```

Unfortunately my regex `^([A-Za-z_]+(ID)?)([A-Z]+\d+|[A-Z]+|\d+)?$` does not work.
Can anybody point out the problem in this regex?
For `FCF_VD_ID_L1` I receive `('FCF_VD_ID_L', None, '1')` which is completely not what I require.

Comment: can you provide exact input and exact output?

Comment: Maybe you just want `re.findall(r'(\w+)_(\w+)', text)`? Or, `(\w+)_(L?\d+|FCV|[AH]|[A-Za-z]*ID)\b`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NbU4ja/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is way too robust and hardcoded

Comment: Perhaps like this `^([^_\n]+(?:_[^_\n]+)*?)(?:_(L[1-8]|FCV|[A-Z]|[1-8]|ID))?$` https://regex101.com/r/4QnKNy/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for this regex:

```
(\w+?)(?:_(L[1-8]|FCV|[A-H])|([1-8]))?$
```

which matches a minimal number of word characters (`\w+?`) followed by an `enum` part of `_` and `L1-L8`, `FCV` or `A-H`, or a digit in the range `1-8`.

Note since you are using `re.match` no `^` is required at the beginning since `re.match` anchors all matches to the start of the string.

In python:

```py
import re

strs = [
  'FCF_VD_ID', 'FCF_VD_Alert_L1', 'FCF_VD_Alert_L8',
  'FCF_VD_SyncID', 'FCF_VRU_Alert_FCV', 'FCF_VRU_Alert_A',
  'FCF_VRU_Alert_H', 'COM_Cam_Frame_1', 'COM_Cam_Frame_8',
  'idObject1'
]

regex = '(\w+?)(?:_(L[1-8]|FCV|[A-H])|([1-8]))?$'

for s in strs:
    core, enum1, enum2 = re.match(regex, s).groups()
    enum = enum1 if enum1 else enum2
    print(s + ' => ', (core, enum))
```

Output:

```
FCF_VD_ID =>  ('FCF_VD_ID', None)
FCF_VD_Alert_L1 =>  ('FCF_VD_Alert', 'L1')
FCF_VD_Alert_L8 =>  ('FCF_VD_Alert', 'L8')
FCF_VD_SyncID =>  ('FCF_VD_SyncID', None)
FCF_VRU_Alert_FCV =>  ('FCF_VRU_Alert', 'FCV')
FCF_VRU_Alert_A =>  ('FCF_VRU_Alert', 'A')
FCF_VRU_Alert_H =>  ('FCF_VRU_Alert', 'H')
COM_Cam_Frame_1 =>  ('COM_Cam_Frame', '1')
COM_Cam_Frame_8 =>  ('COM_Cam_Frame', '8')
idObject1 =>  ('idObject', '1')
```

Comment: That's probably very close to what I am searching for. But specifically I aim for that last enum which can start with '_' or not. If we have something like idObject1 I want that 1 to be the enum. The input in the post's description is just an example.

Comment: @FilipSzczybura this is why it's really important to include *all* forms of sample data in your question. Your problem though is what about something like `abcID`; is that `(abcID, None)` or `(abcI, D)`?

Comment: 'All' means thousands. '(\w+?)(?:_?(\\d+|[A-Z]+\\d+|[A-Z]+))?$' is closest what I am searching for, but I want to exclude 'ID|Id|id' from enum extraction. So for COM_Cam_Sync_ID I don't want do get the enum

Comment: Do any of the enums *have* to have `_` before them? or is it optional for all of them? If it is, I don't see how you can tell whether `ABC` should be `(ABC, None)` or `(AB, C)` (since `C` is a valid enum)

Comment: Most of these enums will have leading _. The exception is a single digit enum like idObject1. Here the enum is 1. Otherwise I want to get any enum that is: _[A-Z]+\\d+ or _[A-Z]+ or without _ just \\d+. You can notice that enums after _ always are uppercase

Comment: @FilipSzczybura see my edit. I think that will work based on your previous comment

Comment: Allright I think this one, made based on your example is suitable: '(\\w+?)(?:(\\d+)|(_[A-Z]\\d+)|(_[A-Z]))?$' ;)

Comment: @FilipSzczybura yeah, that looks like the generic version of what I edited my answer to. I'm glad we got it working. Note that if there can only be a single digit, you should just use `\d` rather than `\d+` as it will make the regex engine's matching easier.

Comment: Thanks! I cannot assume that it is a single digit, because the pickles in which these strings are the keys can contain lot of enumerated fields. But thanks to your answer i was finally capable of writing the regex that works! ☺️